# Is there any evidence that 'knei bosem' is cannabis or ganja?

Tags: word-study, exodus, plants-and-animals

Some [sites](http://www.herbmuseum.ca/node/1565) claim that *kaneh bosem* from [Exodus 30:23](http://biblehub.com/exodus/30-23.htm) is [ganja](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ganja).

I've seen this verse translated variously as:

- fragrant calamus
- aromatic cane (from cane balsm)
- sweet calamus
- fragrant reeds

However, there is a speculation that *kaneh bosem* is a plural form of *kaneh bos*. I don't know of any Bible translation that translates it this way even though it seems to fit some properties.

Is there any evidence that this phrase should be translated 'ganja'?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Is there any evidence that this phrase should be translated 'ganja'?

No.

Exodus 30:23 (ESV) reads:

> Take the finest spices: of liquid myrrh 500 shekels, and of sweet-smelling cinnamon half as much, that is, 250, and 250 of aromatic cane (*qənêh-bōśem*)

The OP points out:

> there is a speculation that kaneh bosem is a plural form of kaneh bos.

This is based, presumably, on a misunderstanding of the ending `em` on *bōśem*. This is superficially similar to [the masculine plural -*ı̂m* ending](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Gesenius%27_Hebrew_Grammar/87._Of_the_Plural) in Hebrew. However, the term *qənêh-bōśem* is singular (i.e. 250 shekels-worth of *q-*). The letter `m` is part of the [root bśm](https://archive.org/stream/hebrewenglishlex00browuoft#page/141/mode/1up).<sup>1</sup>  The word *qənêh-* (spelled *qāneh* when alone) is a common term for "cane" or "reed". The phrase, then, is literally "cane of spice". The second noun *bōśem* is taken attributively, hence "fragrant cane". "*Bos*" means nothing in this context.<sup>2</sup>

As for the actual plant referred to in Exodus, I will believe [William Propp's account](https://books.google.com/books/about/Exodus_19_40.html?id=NqM2JAAACAAJ):

> fragrant cane. *Qənē(h) bōśem* is also called *qāne(h)* *haṭṭôb* ‘the sweet cane’ (Jer 6:20; cf. Akkadian *qanû ṭābu*) and simply *qāne(h)* 'cane' (Isa 43:24; Ezek 27:19). Although reeds are found in Israel itself, it is clear from the prophets that this special cane, like frankincense, was imported "from a distant land." Of various grasses valued in Antiquity for their aromatic essences...the variety most familiar to my readers will be East Asian "lemongrass."

Propp equates the terms *bōśem* and *beśem* earlier in the verse (there constructed with "cinnamon").  The emphasis is on their fragrance; there is no evidence of psychedelic properties attributed these plants in the Exodus account.

---

<sub>1. Were it plural, it would be *bəśāmı̂m*.</sub>



<sub>2. The etymologically related botanical term is is not cannabis but [balsam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balsam).</sub>

Comment: So do you know for certain which species kaneh bosem is?

Comment: People feel "presence" of Yahweh when consuming or inhaling the stuff. Such properties are called entheogenic. Which is psychedelic.

Answer (score 7):

To put this as a purely linguistic question: Hebrew qānē is the same word as Sumerian gin, Akkadian qanū, Ugaritic qn, Greek κάννα, Latin canna, all meaning “reed” or “cane”.

Greek κάνναβις, Latin cannabis, English “hemp” is a different word, perhaps ultimately from Sumerian kunibu, all meaning “hemp”.

These two words cannot very well be connected.

Comment: so there is no connection between kanna and kannabis. notice the other alternative, calamus, is herbal ecstasy that's actually poisonous

Comment: @JimThio Both in this comment and your original question, you're chasing [false cognates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_cognate). The site you linked also makes this mistake and demonstrates very poor understanding of the languages it comments on. You should let these much more educated [answers](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/21155/36) set the record straight. No, the connection you are trying to make is not there.

Answer (score 0):

קנה בשׂם translates literally as 'fragrant reed.' There are other instances too. I remember seeing it tractate Sukka regarding a building material.
Even if the incense contained cannabis, it was nowhere nearly as potent as today's and have you ever gotten high from being in a "hotboxed" room?

Jastrow:

> קָנֶה m.

Source: [Jastrow,_קָנֶה.1](https://www.sefaria.org/Jastrow,_%D7%A7%D6%B8%D7%A0%D6%B6%D7%94.1)

Maimonides/Rambam:

> הַמּוֹר הוּא הַדָּם הַצָּרוּר בְּחַיָּה שֶׁבְּהֹדּוּ הַיָּדוּעַ לַכּל שֶׁמִּתְבַּשְּׂמִין בָּהּ בְּנֵי אָדָם בְּכָל מָקוֹם. וְהַקִּנָּמוֹן הוּא הָעֵץ שֶׁבָּא מֵאִיֵּי הֹדּוּ שֶׁרֵיחוֹ טוֹב וּמִתְגַּמְּרִים בּוֹ בְּנֵי אָדָם. וְהַקִּדָּה הִיא הַקּוֹשְׁט. **וּקְנֵה בּשֶֹׁם** הֵם הַקָּנִים הַדַּקִּים כְּתֶבֶן הָאֲדֻמִּים הַבָּאִים מֵאִיֵּי הֹדּוּ וְרֵיחָן טוֹב וְהֵם מִמִּינֵי הַבְּשָׂמִים שֶׁנּוֹתְנִין אוֹתָם הָרוֹפְאִים בְּצֹרִי:
> Musk refers to the blood contained with a wild beast from India that is of universal renown which people everywhere use as a fragrance. Cinnamon is a tree that comes from the Indian islands which has a pleasant fragrance and which people use as incense. The term kidah refers to costus. **Fragrant cane**, refers to thin canes like red straw that come from the Indian islands and have a pleasant fragrance. They are types of herbs that doctors place in balsam.

Source: [Mishneh Torah, Vessels of the Sanctuary and Those Who Serve Therein 1:3](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah,_Vessels_of_the_Sanctuary_and_Those_Who_Serve_Therein.1.3)

Comment: Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives/803#803). I also recommend going through the [Help Center's](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help) sections on both asking and answering questions.